# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to Insert data into Database, but getting problem, error says:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)
```

**Error1 says:-**

```
com.example.db.myDBClass.InsertData(myDBClass.java:51)
```

**Line is:-**

```
long rows = db.insert(TABLE_MEMBER, null, Val);
```

**Error2 says:-**

```
com.example.db.UploadActivity.InsertDatas(UploadActivity.java:271)
```

**Line is:-**

```
long saveStatus = myDb.InsertData(editImageName.getText().toString(),editPersonName.getText().toString(),
                editPersonaEmail.getText().toString(), editPersonTelephone.getText().toString());
```

**Error3 says:-**

```
com.example.db.UploadActivity$3.onClick(UploadActivity.java:429)
```

**Line is:-**

```
InsertDatas();
```

**Log:-**

```
11-23 06:44:55.104: E/SQLiteLog(8297): (20) statement aborts at 6: [INSERT INTO members(PersonTelephone,ImageName,PersonName,PersonEmail) VALUES (?,?,?,?)] datatype mismatch
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297): Error inserting PersonTelephone=234234234324 ImageName=IMG_20131123_044559.jpg PersonName=ASDFDASFASDF PersonEmail=WEREWR@DSFE.COM
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at com.example.db.myDBClass.InsertData(myDBClass.java:51)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at com.example.db.UploadActivity.InsertDatas(UploadActivity.java:271)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at com.example.db.UploadActivity$3.onClick(UploadActivity.java:429)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-23 06:44:55.135: E/SQLiteDatabase(8297):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**myDBClass.java:-**

```
public class myDBClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase";
    // Table Name
    private static final String TABLE_MEMBER = "members";

    public myDBClass(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create Table Name
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMBER + 
                  "(ImageName TEXT(100)," +
                  " PersonName TEXT(100)," +
                  " PersonEmail TEXT(100)," +
                  " PersonTelephone TEXT(100));");

        Log.d("CREATE TABLE","Create Table Successfully");
    }

    // Insert Data
    public long InsertData(String strImageName, String strPersonName, String strPersonEmail, String strPersonTelephone) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         try {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Write Data

            ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
            Val.put("ImageName", strImageName); 
            Val.put("PersonName", strPersonName);
            Val.put("PersonEmail", strPersonEmail);
            Val.put("PersonTelephone", strPersonTelephone);

            long rows = db.insert(TABLE_MEMBER, null, Val);

            db.close();
            return rows; // return rows inserted.

         } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
         }
    }

    // Select Data
    public String[] SelectData(String strImageName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         try {
            String arrData[] = null;    

             SQLiteDatabase db;
             db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data

             Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MEMBER, new String[] { "*" }, 
                        "ImageName=?",
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(strImageName) }, null, null, null, null);

                if(cursor != null)
                {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        arrData = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()];

                        arrData[0] = cursor.getString(0);
                        arrData[1] = cursor.getString(1);
                        arrData[2] = cursor.getString(2);
                        arrData[3] = cursor.getString(3);
                    }
                }
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return arrData;

         } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
         }

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMBER);
        // Re Create on method  onCreate
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

**UploadActivity.java:-**

```
public boolean InsertDatas()
        {
            // Dialog
            final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            AlertDialog ad = adb.create();

            // Check MemberID
            if(editImageName.getText().length() == 0)
            {
                editImageName.setError("Please Enter Image Name");
                editImageName.requestFocus();
                return false;
            }

            // Check Name
            if(editPersonName.getText().length() == 0)
            {
                editPersonName.setError("Please Enter Person Name");
                editPersonName.requestFocus();
                return false;
            }   

            // Check Tel
            if(editPersonaEmail.getText().length() == 0)
            {
                editPersonaEmail.setError("Please Enter Person Email");
                editPersonaEmail.requestFocus();
                return false;
            }       

            // Check Tel
            if(editPersonTelephone.getText().length() == 0)
            {
                editPersonTelephone.setError("Please Enter Telephone Number");
                editPersonTelephone.requestFocus();
                return false;
            }       

            // Save Data
            long saveStatus = myDb.InsertData(editImageName.getText().toString(),
                    editPersonName.getText().toString(),
                    editPersonaEmail.getText().toString(), editPersonTelephone.getText().toString());

            if(saveStatus <=  0)
            {
                ad.setMessage("Error!! ");
                ad.show();
                return false;
            }

             Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,"Add Data Successfully. ",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

            return true;
        }


saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override                   
                        public void onClick(View v) {   

                        InsertDatas();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Try to use instead of TEXT(100) type VARCHAR(100) for columns in members table.

Comment: what is in line 271 & 429 in UploadActivity.java file...

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji by using VARCHAR(100) still getting same error

Comment: @Abhishek I posted please check now

Comment: lol @VeaceslavGaidarji SQLite types TEXT, NUMERIC, INTEGER, REAL, NONE ... VARCHAR is just mapped to TEXT ... there is no differences

Comment: seems like "PersonTelephone=234234234324" is not converted to string

Comment: oh sorry guys, i did mistake, i already created a database with same name, i just changed the name of the database and my work has done..... thanks for efforts

Answer (score 2):

`Error code 20` comes with database existence problem as far as I have seen.
change the name of the database, writing this for those who still look at this post.