# Android data type mismatch (code 20)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a problem about database services. PUT method is working but POST is not working. I got mistake ' data type mismatch (code 20) '

```
public class DatabaseService
{
    public static final DatabaseService instance = new DatabaseService();
    public static DatabaseService getInstance() { return instance; };

    public DatabaseService() {

    }

    public Cursor GET() {
        try {
            Cursor cursor = DatabaseConnectionService
                    .getInstance()
                    .getDatabaseInstance()
                    .rawQuery(VehicleTableModel.getInstance().GetSelectSQL(""), null);
            return cursor;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logs.error(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean POST(ContentValues parametersAndValues) {
        try {
            DatabaseConnectionService
                    .getInstance()
                    .getDatabaseInstance()
                    .insertOrThrow(VehicleTableModel.getInstance().TableName, null, parametersAndValues);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logs.error(ex);
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            return true;
        }
 public boolean PUT(ContentValues parametersAndValues ,String id) {
    try {
        VehicleTableModel vehicleTableModel = VehicleTableModel.getInstance();
        DatabaseConnectionService
                .getInstance()
                .getDatabaseInstance()
                .update(vehicleTableModel.TableName, parametersAndValues, vehicleTableModel.Columns.Id  + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logs.error(ex);
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        return true;
    }
```

This is Table Helper model class;

```
public class BaseTableModel {
    public String DatabaseName = "";
    public int VersionNumber = 0;
    public String TableName = "";
}
```

About table;

```
public class VehicleTableModel extends BaseTableModel {

private static final VehicleTableModel instance = new VehicleTableModel();
public static VehicleTableModel getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
public VehicleTableModel() {
    this.DatabaseName = "vehicle";
    this.VersionNumber = 1;
    this.TableName = "vehicles";
}
```

What can i do? I researched but i didn't find anything.
Thanks.

Comment: Your `put` method likely 'works' because it is eating the errors while `post` uses `insertOrThrow`. You have an underlying db issue. I've never used a blank database name, perhaps that's the underlying issue? [see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32697315/2350083)

Comment: Actually the table name is dynamic. It comes from here.'about table' Sorry, this is my fault, i did not attach. please, look now..

Comment: I fixed. Thanks a lot.